# Matlab - find out to which of three matrices another one is the most similar

Tags: matlab, matrix, distance, similarity, calculation

so I have three pre-defined 1 row matrices

for example:

```
a = [0.4 0.25 0.5 -0.6 0.2]
b = [-0.8 0 0 0.7 -0.25]
c = [0.15 -0.4 -0.8 0.3 -0.05]
```

and the I have another matrix with multiple rows, such as:

```
x = [0.78   0.51    -0.27   -1.18   1.12;
    -1.28   0.51    -0.27   1.22    1.12;
    -1.28   0.96    -0.27   -0.22   0.14;
    1.30    0.51    0.71    -1.18   0.63;
    0.78    -1.32   -1.76   0.25    -1.79]
```

is there a way to figure out to which of the pre-defined matrices each row of matrix x is most similar to?

For example to get a result such as: "Row 1 is most similar to a; Row 2 is most similar to c, and so on?

Thank you in advance

I have tried pdist() to calculate the distance of matrix x to one of the pre defined matrices which is a nice start to see the difference of each element to the desired element but I don't really know if that is the right way to start and if yes I'm not sure how to go on...

Comment: You have first to decide and define mathematically what is your measure of similarity; [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) and [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Higher_dimensions) are the most trivial, but there are many other possibilities, depending on the field and purpose of your computation.

Answer (score 0):

[`pdist2`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html#d124e753077) is the function that calculates the distance (aka dissimilarity) between two sets of observations.

So, you want to combine your observations into one matrix (ie `[a;b;c]`), and then use `pdist2`. Fortunately, there are flags to get the indices of the observations with the `'Smallest'` dissimilarity (i.e. the greatest similarity).

so, `[D, I] = pdist2([a;b;c], x, 'euclidean', 'smallest', 1)` returns `I = [1 2 2 1 3]` , and so row 1 is closest to a, row 2 to b, 3 to b, 4 to a, and 5 to c.

As a caveat: see the comment by @kikon. 'Similarity' is context-dependent, and needs a precise mathematical formulation. See the examples on the [doc page](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html#d124e753566) as a starting point - you will have to choose one.